# Nonetype has no attribute 'next' in linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm stuck, I can't see what is the problem in my code. here it is:

```
class Node :
  def __init__(self,data=0,next=None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next

class LinkedList: 
  def __init__(self,head=None):
    self.head = head

  def append(self,data):
    new_Node = Node(data)
    if (self.head):
      cons = self.head
      while(cons):
        cons = cons.next
      cons.next = new_Node  
    else:
      self.head = new_Node
  def printt(self):
    cons = self.head
    while(cons):
      print(cons.data)
      cons = cons.next
Q = LinkedList()
Q.append(3)
Q.append(4)
Q.printt()
```

and the error msg is

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/18c2fb2c9abeb710/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    Q.append(4)
  File "/tmp/sessions/18c2fb2c9abeb710/main.py", line 16, in append
    cons.next = new_Node  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I tried to fix the error but failed to solve it.
Please can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error in the line :

```
while(cons):
```

You have to stop when `cons.next` is None. In your case, you code will run till `cons` becomes `None`. Then on the next line, you have the  statement  `cons.next = new_Node`, which essentially checks `None.next` and hence the error.

So use `cons.next` instead of just `cons`. The following will work fine -

```
class Node :
  def __init__(self,data=0,next=None):
    self.data = data
    self.next = next

class LinkedList: 
  def __init__(self,head=None):
    self.head = head

  def append(self,data):
    new_Node = Node(data)
    if (self.head):
      cons = self.head
      while(cons.next):
        cons = cons.next
      cons.next = new_Node  
    else:
      self.head = new_Node
  def printt(self):
    cons = self.head
    while(cons):
      print(cons.data)
      cons = cons.next
Q = LinkedList()
Q.append(3)
Q.append(4)
Q.printt()
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to change the line :

```
while(cons):
```

to -

```
while(cons.next):
```

because otherwise, `cons` is already `None` when you leave the loop.

Comment: **-----------------thanks so much--------------------------- **